# Accessing POST data from plain HTML form in Django CBV

Tags: python, django, post, django-class-based-views

Accessing GET data from a plain HTML form in a Class-Based TemplateView is straightforward. I'm currently doing it like the following:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'some-template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET:
            # do things...

        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

But I'm wondering how I can access POST data. I have tried using `get_context_data()` to check for `post`ed form data...but have been unsuccessful.

**Question:** Can POSTed form data from a plain HTML form (not a Django form) be accessed via a TemplateView?

Comment: TemplateView inherits View, so simply declare `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Yep, totally overlooked it. Here's a link to the appropriate docs, for anyone who runs across this in the future: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference in the way the data is sent between a Django form and anything else: it's in `request.POST` as always.

Naturally, you need to define the `post` method, rather than `get`.

Comment: Well there was the issue. I never defined the `post` method. Doh! I'll close this up in a few minutes.